# Functional programming: When to use which abstraction

Tags: functional-programming, abstraction

There are a lot of patterns in Functional programming. e.g. Monoids, Monads, Functors e.t.c But these are very high level abstraction and one doesn't really know when to use which one.

e.g. Monoids are useful when you want to reduce several items of A to a single item of A

In that sense, what problem are each of these abstractions trying to solve?
Maybe we can show how programmers dealt with a problem before `monoid` were discovered vs how they deal with the same problem by using `monoid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those *patterns* are mathematical concepts, they either apply to your program or they don't. You can write the exact same code without them, you just will start to notice that lots of your functions for different data types share a common structure.

And not only do you need different functions for every data type to deal with this common thing, but also all helper functions will need to be rewritten for every data type. This is when you find that you want to use an abstraction. You check which typeclass matches the common structure and provides the expected helper functions, and then apply it to your data type.

---

About your specific example: Before [`Monoid`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) were "discovered", everyone used `++` to append two lists, and `concat` to append multiple lists. Likewise they used `+` to sum two numbers, and `sum` to sum multiple ones. If someone wrote a tree whose elements should be folded into a single value, he had to write one implementation for lists, and one implementation for numbers, using the respective operation.
Now, with monoids, we can abstract over the concrete type, and write a tree implementation for arbitrary monoids. We use the `mappend` and `mconcat` operations instead of the specific ones, and our tree works for lists and numbers both. And any other monoid even.